# Do Any Existing Languages Allow Function Arguments In Arbitrary Places In A Function Name?

Tags: language-agnostic, syntax, programming-languages, lang

When we write (in some language or another):

```
   lengthOf(n)
```

We think of it as short for an english 'fill in the blanks' construction, like:

```
  length of __
```

But when we write things like these:

```
  isAnInteger(n)
  appendTo(n,m)
```

We think of sentences like:

```
  __ is an integer
  append ___  to  ___
```

**So, it would seem more natural to allow function invocation expressions like:**

```
  (n)isAnInteger
  append(n)to(m)
```

Where the 'function names' are something like:

```
  _isAnInteger
  append_to_
```

**Can anyone name existing programming languages which allow this?**  I know object-oriented languages let the object be one argument at the front, but I am wondering about more flexible syntaxes.

Comment: Objective-C method invocations are often of the form `[anObject performOperation:operation withTask:task andInteger:integer]`, etc. It's not _flexible_ per se, but (IMO) reads more naturally.

Comment: You can define infix functions in Standard ML.  For example, you can define a function `to` so that the caller writes `n to m` instead of `to(n, m)`.  That's not exactly what you're looking for, but it does share some similarities (especially since you can write both `append` and `to` in order to call `append(n to m)` later).

Comment: Smalltalk, Objective-C, Agda, BitC, and others. See [Is there a language out there in which parameters are placed inside the method name?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/102906/) and [Has whitespace in identifiers ever been idiomatic?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/145751/)

Comment: @SedateAlien Objective-C has keyword arguments?

Answer (score 3):

Mixfix is the most general form of what is presented above as a Smalltalk syntax feature via Objective-C. [Maude's "bubble" parsing](http://maude.cs.uiuc.edu/maude1/manual/maude-manual-html/maude-manual_31.html) is the most clearly documented implementation of this. More generally, [google for "mixfix parsing"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mixfix%20parsing).

Answer (score 3):

As Brian Rice pointed out, mixfix notation in Maude handles this exactly. You've even got the correct syntax.

Your examples

```
_isAnInteger
append_to_
```

Would be declared in Maude as

```
op _IsAnInteger : Int -> Bool
op append_to_ : Int List -> List
```

And would be called as

```
5 IsAnInteger
append 5 to L
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, such a thing does exist, but not in the exact syntax presented in the question.

In JavaScript it's called *chaining* and is commonly found in frameworks like jQuery to make it easy to create and modify DOM elements on the fly:

```
$('<div/>')
 .css('background', '#f00')
 .css('width', '100px')
 .css('height', '100px')
 .hide()
 .appendTo('BODY')
 .fadeIn();
```

The preceding jQuery snippet creates an `DIV` element, sets the width, height and background color, hides the `DIV`, appends it to the document and applies a fade-in effect.

Syntax is important. Given the following example:

```
(n)isAnInteger
append(n)to(m)
```

The parentheses obviously are mean to be function argument delimiters. But you also need function name delimiters and object/thing delimiters. A better syntax would be:

```
n.isAnInteger().append(n).to(m)
```

Which is very similar the jQuery syntax:

```
 $('DIV')
  .filter(':visible')
  .appendTo('#new_element');
```

Which will find `DIV` elements that are visible and copy them to the element with an id of `new_element`.

Comment: The asker is not asking about a *better* syntax, they are asking about a *specific* syntax.

Comment: function chaining is anything but *arbitrary*.

Answer (score 1):

Smalltalk is pretty close. (it is the same syntax as Objective-C, mentioned in another answer)

Message sends in Smalltalk do no use braces, but follow the form `doSomething:with:`

So you can write:

```
5 isInteger
aList appendTo: anotherList
aList at: aPosition ifAbsent: anAction
```

All messages are sent to an object (the receiver) that must be on the left, so you can *not* write:

```
append: aList to: anotherList   "illegal syntax"
```

The syntax `doSomething:with:` is more natural than using braces. You are less easily confused about which parameter is what. Consider for instance:

```
   aList.sublist( i, j )
   aList sublistFrom: i to: j
```

With proper naming of the methods, it's clear the the first argument is the lower index, and the second the upper index, unlike with braces.

Answer (score 1):

[Grace](http://gracelang.org) is a new educational language (still in development), which supports an almost arbitrary order of arguments:

```
class MyObject {
    method choseBetween (a : Block<None>) and (b : Block<None>) -> None {
        if (Random.nextBoolean)
            then { a.apply } else { b.apply } }
}
```

which could get called as:

```
MyObject.new.chooseBetween { print("Yes") } and { print("No") }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-c#Messages) probably comes closest. Example:

```
- (void)setRangeStart:(int)start end:(int)end;

- (void)importDocumentWithName:(NSString *)name withSpecifiedPreferences:
(Preferences *)prefs beforePage:(int)insertPage;
```

Called like:

```
[obj setRangeStart:1 end:42];
[obj importDocumentWithName:@"foo" withSpecifiedPreferences:prefs beforePage:1];
```

It doesn't allow `[obj 5:isAnInteger]` though.

Answer (score 0):

Two languages with mixfix operators support come to my mind: [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/agda.php?n=ReferenceManual.Mixfix) and [BitC](http://www.bitc-lang.org/browse/compiler/MixFixProcessing.html).